# How to change the text of a <label> which is hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change the text of a label whose parent has its display hidden. I am not able to access the label because of its parents visibility.

I would like to know is there a way to change the text of this label without the changing the visibility of the parent.

I tried changing the visibility of the label and changing the text and hiding it back, did not work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#394").find(".name").children("label").text("Home");
```

});

```
<div class="sample1" style="display: none;">
<div id="394">
    <div class="name">
        <label>house.jpg</label>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions/ideas?

**Answer:**

First, Thank you all for the response.

I fixed the issue.

This is the change I made and it worked.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".sample1").find(".name").children("label").text("Home");
});

<div class="sample1" style="display: block;">
<div style="display: none;" id="398">
    <div class="name">
        <label>Sample</label>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: A label isn't supposed to change really, maybe you mean an input? Please post an example of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Hidden elements can be selected just like visible ones; it's only a little more complicated if they are not in the DOM anymore.

Comment: you can also use .html().  For example :  $(".sample1").find(".name").children("label").html("Home");

Comment: Please answer your own question with your solution and mark it as the accepted answer. This makes it easier for other users to find the solution and keeps the community bot from bumping this question because it thinks it is unresolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Sample**
(Updated) http://jsfiddle.net/SXLnt/1/
(Old) http://jsfiddle.net/SXLnt/

**Solution**

```
$("#394 label").text("new_house.jpg");
$(".sample1").show(); // show hidden result
```

---

**Sample HTML**

```
<form id="parent_form" style="display: none; visibility: hidden;">
  <label for="male" id="lb_male">Male</label>
  <input type="radio" name="sex" id="male" />
  <br />
  <label for="female" id="lb_female">Female</label>
  <input type="radio" name="sex" id="female" />
</form>
```

**Sample JS (jQuery)**

```
$("#lb_male").text("Man");     // Change text 1
$("#lb_female").text("Woman"); // Change text 2
//$("#parent_form").show();      // Show parent
```

**Sample DOM result**
[image: JSFiddle result]

Comment: I really appreciate the response. But I have posted the code now which is not working for me.

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker I updated my answer to your question edit. Please review. See also: http://jsfiddle.net/SXLnt/1/

Comment: If have a label in a div with display :none and want to change the text from javascript dynamically before it set display :block. $("#ID_Label").text("new text"); is the ONLY, that works for me - Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

IF the label's ID is lblSomething, you could do it in JQuery as so ...
`$("lblSomething").val("Changed value")`
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If what you posted is your full code, it looks like you are missing a closing tag on your outer div. Try this:

```
<div class="sample1" style="display: none;">
  <div id="394">
    <div class="name">
        <label>house.jpg</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No I missed it here. I changed it now.